# How to set many columns on Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to insert more than a hundred columns into a CSV file. But seems pandas library has limited columns.

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metric.py", line 91, in <module>
    finalFile(sys.argv[1])
  File "metric.py", line 80, in finalFile
    data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, dtype=str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2010, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 540, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

And below is my function:

```
def finalFile(fname):

    output = pd.DataFrame()

    for file_name in os.listdir('test/sciprt-temp/'):
        if file_name.startswith(fname):
            with open(os.path.join('test/sciprt-temp/', file_name)) as f:
                data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, dtype=str)
                output[file_name.rsplit('.', 4)[2]] = data[1]

    output.insert(0, 'timestamp', dt.datetime.now().timestamp())
    output.insert(0, 'hostname', fname.rsplit('-', 3)[0])
    output.set_index(output.columns[0], inplace=True)
    output.to_csv(fname.rsplit('.', 2)[2] + ".csv")



finalFile(sys.argv[1])
```

It seems to work fine when inserting few columns but not working with more columns.

```
hostname,timestamp,-diskstats_latency-sda-avgrdwait-g,-diskstats_latency-sda-avgwait-g,-diskstats_latency-sda-avgwrwait-g,-diskstats_latency-sda-svctm-g,-diskstats_latency-sda_avgwait-g
test.test.com,1617779170.62498,2.7979746835e-03,6.6681051841e-03,7.1533659185e-03,2.5977601795e-04,6.6681051841e-03
```

Comment: "I want to insert", but you are reading csv in `File "metric.py", line 80, in finalFile`?

Comment: @MustafaAydın I try to loop the filename and set it into a CSV file. but it work when I loop around 20 files but when I loop more file around hundred it was an error: pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file.

Comment: Can you share an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? As far as the traceback goes you are *read*ing a CSV file not writing one.

Comment: ...and maybe that part of the code where you are looping.

Comment: @MustafaAydın I had update my code in my question above. Could you take a look?

Comment: Okay, the issue is one of the files that meet your criterion is probably empty, and error arises when you are trying `read_csv` on it. Please check the files in the directory, or debug the program e.g. print `file_name` in the `if` statement and see after which you get this error.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Yeah you are right because I have many files but some files are missing content inside. Thank you so much for your help.